# How to detect one array list include some element in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

Assume I declared an Array `isFind[]` like this,

```
bool[] isFind = new bool[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
   isFind[i] = init(); // initialize isFind[]
}

bool init();
{
  ...; // some code here
}
```

Is there any quick method (less typing code) to detect there is `false` element or not in `isFind[]`?
I don't want to `for/foreach Loop` each element in the array list.

**[Update]**

.NET 2.0 Used.

quick method (less typing code)

Comment: What do you mean by 'a quick method'? Better performance or less typing?

Comment: What I mean should be less typing. :-). Sorry for unclear defined at the beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using .NET2 then you can use the static [`TrueForAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2kykt9x%28VS.80%29.aspx) method:

```
bool allTrue = Array.TrueForAll(isFind, delegate(bool b) { return b; });
```

Comment: +1 for showing `Array.TrueForAll` method (I never noticed there was such)

Comment: Thanks for correct & edit my original question. Finally I implement my code with your method.

Comment: +1. Never used that one, goot tip. `Array.IndexOf` is shorter and faster, though ;)

Comment: @Jaroslav: Yes, in this case `IndexOf` will be marginally faster. But in cases where the predicate is more complicated than just a straight match then you'd have to use `TrueForAll` rather than `IndexOf`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have .NET 3.5 or higher you can use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
isFind.Any(x => !x)
```

From your update to the question you are using .NET 2.0 so writing out the loop is probably the best option.

Comment: I am not sure I can use `Any()` or not in .NET 2.0. I tried the way in VS2005 just now, but I can't find it. Thank you.

Comment: Just performance point: `Any<T>` does foreach internally so it is only a code shortcut, not a performance shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 2.0 version:

```
bool []isFind = new bool[3];

isFind[0] = true;
isFind[1] = true;
isFind[1] = false;

bool exists = (Array.IndexOf(isFind, false) != -1);
```

The code uses an internal for loop.
Also you had the array declaration wrong.

Comment: It used to be `bool isFind[] = new isFind[5];` (as copied in other answers).

Answer (score 2):

The only way to find something is to look for it. Assuming that your array is not sorted (if it were, you would only need to look at the first or last element, depending on the sorting), and you have no external cache, you have to check all its elements, so you need a loop. It does not matter if you write it explicitly or through another function, the loop will be there somehow.

Comment: You don't always have to check all the elements. If you find one that is false then you don't need to check the rest.

Comment: @Mark: Well, I took that for granted. But you have to be prepared to check them all in case you don't find the one you are looking for. And you have to loop, no matter whether you stop soon or not.

Comment: +1, the loop will be definitely somewhere, but in some cases existing loops can be reused. (Like checking for false in initialization loop rather than creating a new loop just for checking.)

Comment: @Regent: You are right. If you know that checking for any `false` value in the array will be important, using a external cache (as you propose in your own answer) is a good idea. The more you know about the potential uses of your class, the better you can prepare for them and the happier your clients will be.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not use a seperate loop to find false elements. (There is in general, no way to perform comparison on n objects without looping over all of them at least once.) For a five member array, loop cost is negligible. If you are using bigger arrays, look at [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3we7ff2.aspx) for performance/space benefits.

```
bool isFind[] = new isFind[5];
bool falseExists = false;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
   isFind[i] = init(); // initialize isFind[]
   if(!isFind[i])
       falseExists=true;
}

bool init();
{
  ...; // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can record whether any element was `false` during initialization phase:

```
bool isFind[] = new isFind[5];
bool containsFalse = false;

for (int i = 0; i < isFind.Length; i++)
{
   if (!(isFind[i] = init())) // initialize isFind[]                                 
      containsFalse = true; // and record if item was false
}
```